# Java - having trouble breaking out of while loops

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to write a java program to where the user inputs a string representing a binary number (0s and 1s). The program should verify that input is a binary number and if that is not the case, the program prints a message that the number is not a valid binary number. If the user input is acceptable, the program should count how many 1's are in that word and output the count.

Here's what I have so far, but when I input a string like "1234" and get to the third while loop it just keeps reprinting the message "Your number can only contain ones and zeros. Please ever a binary value containing only ones and zeros: ", even if I enter a valid string like "0010". I've been racking my brain on this for a few days, so any assistance is much appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;


    System.out.println("Welcome to the binary scanner!");
    System.out.print("Please enter a string in binary fashion: ");

    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
       System.out.println("That's not a binary number...\nPlease enter a binary number");
       String temp = scan.nextLine();
    }

    input = scan.nextLine();
    input = input.trim();


    while (!input.contains("1")){
        System.out.println("Your number does not contain any ones.\nPlease enter a binary number that contains ones.");
        input = scan.nextLine();            
    }



    while (input.contains("2") || input.contains("3") || input.contains("4") || input.contains("5") || input.contains("6") || input.contains("7") || input.contains("8") || input.contains("9")){
        System.out.println ("Your number can only contain ones and zeros.\nPlease ever a binary value containing only ones and zeros: ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
    }


    while (input.contains("1")){ 
        boolean notOne = false;
        int oneCount = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++){
            char c = input.charAt(x);
            if (c == '1' || c == '0'){
                if (c == '1'){
                    oneCount++;
                    notOne = true;
                    }
            }
            else {
                notOne = false;
            }


            }System.out.println("The binary string contains " + oneCount + (oneCount == 1 ? " one." : " ones."));
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You here break out of the `for` loop.

Comment: I'd recommend using a regular expression for checking to make sure only zeros and ones are contained in the string.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/idQDI0

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. I couldn't reproduce your issue (I gave input as 1234 first and next I gave input as 0010 and it worked fine). However I made some modifications to your code as your last while loop is useless. Please try using 'Debugger' to identify your issue or post some screenshots to prove your issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the binary scanner!");
    System.out.print("Please enter a string in binary fashion: ");

    while (!scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.println("That's not a binary number...\nPlease enter a binary number");
        String temp = scan.nextLine();
    }

    String input = scan.nextLine();
    input = input.trim();


    while (!input.contains("1"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your number does not contain any ones.\nPlease enter a binary number that contains ones.");
        input = scan.nextLine();
    }


    while (input.contains("2") || input.contains("3") || input.contains("4") || input.contains("5") || input.contains("6") || input.contains("7") || input.contains("8") || input.contains("9"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your number can only contain ones and zeros.\nPlease ever a binary value containing only ones and zeros: ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
    }


    int oneCount = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++)
    {
        char c = input.charAt(x);
        if (c == '1')
        {
            oneCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The binary string contains " + oneCount + (oneCount == 1 ? " one." : " ones."));

}
```